# Express and Multer large file uploads throwing ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: node.js, json, express, multer

I have built a web app were user uploads 2 JSON files consist of integer values and the front-end posts to the server (using Multer) where these 2 JSON files are compared against each other to calculate the difference and intersection of the values in each JSON files.

It works with small JSON files, however it throws ERR_CONNECTION_RESET when I try to upload large JSON files with lots of values(about 100k).

**Front-end**, simple HTML:

```
<form action="http://localhost:3000/api/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" accept=".json" multiple /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Back-end:**

server.js/app.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const router = require("./routes/routes");

app.use("/api/upload", router);
app.listen(3000);
```

routes.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const multer = require("multer");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const router = express.Router();

let oneValues = new Array(); // array to store the values of file 1
let twoValues = new Array(); // array to store the values of file 2

// Multer storage
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "./uploads");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

// main router and processing logic
router.post("/", upload.array("file"), (req, res, next) => {
  const one = require("../uploads/1.json"); // accessing uploaded file 1
  const two = require("../uploads/2.json"); // accessing uploaded file 2

  // iterating the file 1 and storing the values in oneValues array
  for (let i = 0; i < one.length; i++) {
    oneValues[i] = one[i].value;
  }

  // iterating the file 2 and storing the values in twoValues array
  for (let i = 0; i < two.length; i++) {
    twoValues[i] = two[i].value;
  }

  // 3 logics to find the difference and intersection
  let differenceOne = oneValues.filter((x) => !twoValues.includes(x));
  let differenceTwo = twoValues.filter((x) => !oneValues.includes(x));
  let intersection = oneValues.filter((x) => twoValues.includes(x));

  // sending the results back to front-end
  res.json({ differenceOne, differenceTwo, intersection });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Datasets:**
These are the very small JSON files which works fine

1.json:

```
[
  {
    "value": 1
  },
  {
    "value": 2
  },
  {
    "value": 3
  },
  {
    "value": 4
  },
  {
    "value": 5
  }
]
```

2. json:

```
[
  {
    "value": 1
  },
  {
    "value": 2
  },
  {
    "value": 6
  },
  {
    "value": 7
  }
]
```

Here is the large JSON files which has has about 100k values:
https://file.io/rQZfpnPENtfR

Thank you!

Comment: Don't forget adding try catch block to analyze errors

Comment: I'm new to this, can you please direct me which lines to place in the try catch block?

Answer (score 0):

You may try one of these:

A:

```
var server = app.listen(300);
server.setTimeout(500000);
```

B:

```
app.use(express.limit('100M'));
```

C:

```
var upload = multer({ storage : storage2, limits: { fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 50 } });
```

Comment: I tried all these but it didnt work